# Convert GM_addstyle to add the style without GM

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm using a browser that does not support any addons but supports javascript & CSS. I can't seem to get this javascript to work and have narrowed it down to this part. By my basic knowledge I assume GM_addstyle works on the Greasemonkey addon & since my browser (Rambox) I'm using to access this specific website that I want this script to run, it won't

I don't have experience with JS yet to do it myself so could someone convert this into general non-Gm style. Much Thanks

```
GM_addStyle(`
.notion-frame span .katex {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a `<style>` tag to the page which has `textContent` of that string:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
.notion-frame span .katex {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
`;
```